# permission denied publickey using rsync with GCP

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, rsync

I'm trying to connect with rsync to a GCP vm. Whenever I do, I'm getting weird errors related to permissions.

I've checked that my username is part of the sudoers group so I can't really see where the issue is coming from. I logged in to my GCP instance which created a user dir under /home following my Mac OS username format,

Here are the commands I've been trying, and the results...

```
C02YT3UDLVDL:proj-name j.lname$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine    
j.lname@xx.xxx.xxx.xx The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx.xxx.xxx.xx)' 
can't be established. ECDSA key fingerprint is 
SHA256:JW7VfidHTsAtq8JjF9bEkdfIjdskIAadfs80.Are you sure you want to continue  
connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx' (ECDSA) to 
the list of known hosts.
```

After which I try moving a test dir...

```
rsync -Pavz testDir/* xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/j.lname
```

And get

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Trying it one more time get:

```
 $ rsync -Pavz testDir/* xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/j.lname/
 The authenticity of host 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx (xx.xxx.xxx.xx)' can't be established.
 ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:Q8kqWi3iyLno3Q8kqWi3iyLno3Q8kqWi3iyLno3.
 ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:ff:56:c3:21:cc:f1:a7:62:1b:72:bc:54:8e:f7:c8:1a.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
 Warning: Permanently added 'xx.xx.xx.xx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
 yPermission denied (publickey).
```

Edited:

At the advice of someone on here also tried

```
rsync -Pavz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine" testDir/* 
j.lname@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/j.lname/
```

And that time got:

```
bash: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far)   
[sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at 
io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Answer (score 0):

With rsync you have to specify the ssh key as you do with ssh. That's why you get a permission denied. We can do it with the -e option :

```
rsync -Pavz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine" testDir/* j.lname@xx.xxx.xxx.xx:/home/j.lname
```

Edit:

Rsync command should be installed on the destination server too

Comment: Thanks for your help....I still ran into a little weirdness trying that way (edited above to show that)

Comment: You miss the rsync command on your destination server

Comment: mmm its definitely installed there...

Comment: @JTK maybe a path issue, check there : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198757

Answer (score 0):

Something to add to make sure is understood to anyone coming upon this... is that you need to do the ssh key-gen process on both the source and destination machines.

This means making sure the contents of source's id_rsa.pub are saved in destination's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` folder... AND... vice versa (destination's id_rsa.pub saved over to the same location in the source)

Do some other searching on the chmod permissions that need to be set on the public keys, private keys, and authorized_keys folder because apparently that's important too.